# How do I change the real public path of my website?

Tags: php, global

My website script is currently installed in the root of my domain. I want to move it to a new directory called /script. The script creator said to edit the globals.php file so that the public_html root location of the script is changed to my new location which is /script.

I don't know any PHP though. What do I change here?

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
define('REAL_PUBLIC_PATH',dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));#getcwd()); // e.g. /home/user/public_html
define("PHP_DIR",REAL_PUBLIC_PATH."/../ClixScript_PHP_DOCS/"); // DEFINE THE PATH TO your ClixScript_PHP_DOCS folder here...
define('STORAGE_DIR',PHP_DIR.'storage/');
define("PHP_ERRORS_DIR",@constant("STORAGE_DIR")."err/PHP_errors.log");
define("START_MICROTIME",microtime(true));
define('REAL_PUBLIC_DIR',basename(getcwd())); // e.g public_html
define('RUN_HOOK',PHP_DIR.'runHook.php');
define('ASSET_POINTS',0);
define('ASSET_CASH',1); // USD
define('ASSET_TE_CREDITS',250); // Traffic Exchange Credits
define('CONTROLLER_DIR',constant("PHP_DIR").'controller/');
```

Comment: Did you try to just move it? At first glance, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Where is ClixScript_... located (absolute path)?

Comment: Good question. It's located next to my /public_html path, next to /www, /bin, /etc, /ssl, etc. Do you know how I can figure out the absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Search:**

define("PHP_DIR",REAL_PUBLIC_PATH."/../ClixScript_PHP_DOCS/");

**Replace with:**

define("PHP_DIR",REAL_PUBLIC_PATH."/../../ClixScript_PHP_DOCS/");

Comment: Hey, I have another issue. Are you still available?

Comment: Please visit my site at https://thespartaninstitute.com/portal

All of the links are still pointing to the old root directory. How can I edit my global.php so that I can add /portal/ to the urls? I believe this has caused issues with the CSS and images.

Comment: @user2443803 ummm... `define('REAL_PUBLIC_DIR',"public_html/portal");` ?? just a guess :-S

Comment: Got this error. Should I keep the #getcwd?

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/thespar/public_html/portal/globals.php on line 5

Comment: @user2443803 corrected it in the comment. Also, REAL_PUBLIC_DIR, not REAL_PUBLIC_PATH ;)

Comment: Okay. Should I delete the getcwd part?

Comment: Sorry about that confusion. Okay, I followed the directions. I'm clearing my cache now.

Comment: Ah yeah, same issue so far.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. (You did replace line 10, not line 5, right?)

Comment: Yep! Do you think we should modify line 5 as well?

Comment: I moved the installation to a subdomain. It worked, and I'm content! haha. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have an index.php file which relies on the root directory of the website. This file then includes all necessary files, no matter where they reside (eg. In a script directory).

Comment: This answer isn't relating to the question at all.